# Openvpn ldap (Active Directory) authentication - Incorrect password supplied for LDAP

Tags: windows, active-directory, openvpn, ldap, authentication

I want to give clients sslvpn service using openvpn server. I wanted to use ldap authentication for authorization in clients.
I prepared the definitions as published on the internet, the sslvpn tunnel is successfully installed without ldap authorization.
When I turn on ldap authorization, it gives the error "invalid credentials" specified in the logs below.
I see that openvpn and active directory are successfully linked for ldap search. But in the password authorization section, although the password is correct, I get incorrect password logs.
In my researches, I found that those who encountered similar situations used some code snippets for ldap search. I still received the same error when I applied the like.
So I didn't know if I was facing a similar error. I shared server, ldap definitions and client definitions at the bottom. I try to understand what the error I received is about.
My guess is that the password was not correctly transmitted to the active directory side, but I could not find how to detect it.
I did not get any results from the searches I made on the internet by saying the search results.
I would appreciate it if anyone guides to solve the problem.

**Server Version/OS**

```
debian based linux

openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.4.0 [git:HEAD/d119a5983835297a+] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jan 31 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=yes enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_plugindir='${prefix}/lib/openvpn' with_sysroot=no
```

**Client Version/OS:**

```
Windows 10

OpenVPN Connect 2.7.1.104
```

**Active Directory OS:**

```
Windows Server 12 r2 (MS server 2016)
```

OpenVPN logs:

```
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]81.81.10.12:63438, sid=99840e06 2fc28386
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=MyOrganizationalUnit/CN=Fort-Funston_CA/name=EasyRSA/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=MyOrganizationalUnit/CN=ovpnClient/name=EasyRSA/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_GUI_VER=ovpnmi_1.0.0
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_VER=3.2__qa:d87f5bbc04)
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_PLAT=win
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_NCP=2
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_TCPNL=1
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: IV_PROTO=2
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: UV_ASCLI_VER=2.7.1.104
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 peer info: UV_PLAT_REL=Windows_10_Enterprise_6.3.18363
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: LDAP bind failed: Invalid credentials (80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580)
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: Incorrect password supplied for LDAP DN "CN=user1,CN=Users,DC=izmir,DC=com,DC=tr".
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1558', remote='link-mtu 1557'
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in local config but missing in remote config, local='comp-lzo'
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 [ovpnClient] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]81.81.10.12:63438
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 Delayed exit in 5 seconds
May 23 14:51:13 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 SENT CONTROL [ovpnClient]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)
May 23 14:51:19 MSRVR openvpn-vtun0[1766]: 81.81.10.12:63438 SIGTERM[soft,delayed-exit] received, client-instance exiting
```

Server configuration:

```
verb 3
status /opt/whynot/etc/openvpn/status/vtun0.status 30
writepid /var/run/openvpn/vtun0.pid
daemon openvpn-vtun0
dev-type tun
dev vtun0
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
iproute /usr/libexec/vyos/system/unpriv-ip
proto udp
persist-tun
mode server
tls-server
keepalive 10 30
management /tmp/openvpn-mgmt-intf unix
push "route 10.100.110.0 255.255.255.0"
server 192.168.168.0 255.255.255.0
ca /config/auth/ovpn/4ldaptest/ca.crt
cert /config/auth/ovpn/4ldaptest/ovpnServer.crt
key /config/auth/ovpn/4ldaptest/ovpnServer.key
dh /config/auth/ovpn/4ldaptest/dh2048.pem
compress lzo
cipher aes-256-cbc
compat-names
--plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so /config/auth/ovpn/auth-ldap-test.conf
--mssfix
```

LDAP plugin configuration:

```
<LDAP>
  # LDAP server URL
  URL ldap://192.168.33.11
  # Bind DN (If your LDAP server doesn’t support anonymous binds)
  BindDN CN=user1,CN=users,DC=izmir,DC=com,DC=tr
  # Bind Password
  Password P1w2DkyW
  # Network timeout (in seconds)
  Timeout  15
  # Enable Start TLS
  TLSEnable no
  # Follow LDAP Referrals (anonymously)
  FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>

<Authorization>
  BaseDN          "DC=izmir,DC=com,DC=tr"
  SearchFilter    "sAMAccountName=%u"
  RequireGroup    false
</Authorization>
```

Client configuration:

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
remote 81.99.81.33 1194
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
cert ovpnClient.crt
key ovpnClient.key
ca ca.crt
```

Answer (score 2):

The log indicates LDAP Bind Failed, so it is not reaching the point that user-credentials may be evaluated.

The BindDN appears unusual: `BindDN CN=user1,CN=users,DC=izmir,DC=com,DC=tr`

At a guess, perhaps that should be: `BindDN CN=user1,OU=users,DC=izmir,DC=com,DC=tr`

Suggest verifying the DN of the account.  Swapping CN for OU in the BindDN will result in the behavior observed.  Otherwise, verify the credentials.